# Call Process with arguments in Swift macOS App

Tags: swift

I'm trying to run a Process from my Swift macOS app. But, I'm having trouble formatting the arguments to my Process.

So far, the following code is working well:

```
let task = Process()
var environment =  ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment
environment["PATH"] = "/usr/local/bin"
task.environment = environment
task.currentDirectoryPath = "/usr/local/bin"
task.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/usr/local/bin/convert")
task.arguments = [filename, filename+".pdf"]
            
let outputPipe = Pipe()
let errorPipe = Pipe()
task.standardOutput = outputPipe
task.standardError = errorPipe
...
try! task.run()
```

When I try and add the arguments `"-trim"`, `"-fuzz 10%"` to the existing `task.arguments` the program crashes. The process error is:

```
New error: convert: unrecognized option `-fuzz 10%' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/1718.
```

How do I properly format these arguments to run the process?

Comment: When you run this command yourself from the terminal, does it work as expected? (e.g. `/usr/local/bin/convert -trim -fuzz 10% <filename> <filename.pdf>`)

Comment: Yes, then the commands are working

Comment: @user2870829 In that case, can you try passing in `"-fuzz"` and `"10%"` as separate arguments? That should work (and if so, I can expand on this in a full answer)

Comment: `@Itai Ferber` is correct, separating the arguments works for me:
 `task.arguments = ["-trim", "-fuzz", "10%", filename, filename+".pdf"]`

Comment: @Itai Ferber Thank you! It is working as expected with seperating the arguments and options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run commands on the command line, your shell typically splits arguments to pass to a program by whitespace — when you run a command like

```
/usr/local/bin/convert -trim -fuzz 10% <input> <output>
```

the shell will split those arguments and pass them along to `convert` like so:

```
["/usr/local/bin/convert", "-trim", "-fuzz", "10%", "<input>", "<output>"]
```

When `convert` goes to parse the arguments you pass in, it iterates over those arguments and attempts to match them against a known list that it accepts. It looks up `-trim`, which it recognizes, and `-fuzz`, which it recognizes, and it accepts `10%` as the argument to `-fuzz`... and so on.

When you execute a program directly from your code, whether through `Process`, or the lower level [`execve`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) or [`posix_spawn`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/posix_spawn.3.html), the arguments that you pass in are forwarded *directly* to the receiving process. In your original case, this means that `convert` received:

```
["/usr/local/bin/convert", "-trim", "-fuzz 10%", "<input>", "<output>"]
```

`convert`, and many other programs, don't *further* split up arguments on whitespace themselves, so when it tried to match the entirety of `-fuzz 10%` as a *single* command line option (space and all), it couldn't find anything.

This is equivalent to running

```
/usr/local/bin/convert -trim "-fuzz 10%" <input> <output>
```

on the command line, where the quotes *prevent* your shell from splitting words on whitespace. When I run that command locally on my machine, I get the exact same error:

```
convert: unrecognized option `-fuzz 10%' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/1718.
```

The solution is to do the same splitting your shell might do, and pass in each argument separately as its own string:

```
task.arguments = ["-trim", "-fuzz", "10%", filename, filename+".pdf"]
```